# Filter Specific dates in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, date

I've called Landsat8 images from 2014 to 2019 using filter date function. But I don't know how can I call Landsat8 images only for June, July, and August from 2014 to 2019?

```
Map.centerObject(geometry);

var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
.filterDate('2014-01-01','2019-01-01')
.filterBounds(geometry);
```

this is code's link:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/5c2959ec6adecfdefa817c37d74effe2

Comment: filtering for a specific one date only? which ee.code should I apply?
like ee.filterDate('2019-07-19')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ee.Filter.calendarRange() on the image collection

```
// filte ron specific month:
var filter = ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,8, 'month');
var filterLandsat = landsat.filter(filter);

print(filterLandsat)
```

[link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ed5156a9a38c3388f7f9ce22af890f8b)